# The verb "need" can't have two objects... But what about "I need + myself + a brand new meaning"?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns, ditransitive-verbs

[Limp Bizkit - My Own Cobain](https://genius.com/Limp-bizkit-my-own-cobain-lyrics):

> I can't believe it's over
> I can't believe I'm broken
> Would someone tell me that it's all just dreaming
> I **need myself a brand new meaning**

**(1)** *I need myself a brand new meaning*.
Is (1) correct?

need + myself (first object) + a brand new meaning (second object):
According to dictionaries, the verb "need" can't have two objects.
Is it grammatically correct to do a ditransitive verb from a non-ditransitive one?
Is it natural?

---

For example:

**(2a)**
*-She said I need a psychiatrist!

-And you?

-And I said she needs **herself** a psychiatrist*!
Is (2a) correct?

**(2b)**
*-She said I need a psychiatrist!

-And you?

-And I said she needs a psychiatrist **herself***!
Is (2b) correct?

**(3)** *I want **myself** that car*.
Is (3) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "myself" or "herself" are not objects, they are only for emphasis.  They don't actually have a role in the clause structure, and "need" isn't functioning as a ditransitive verb.

However the song and the examples below are odd, and the ordering of words is probably more about the music than the grammar.

It would be natural to use the reflexive pronoun for emphasis in the following way:

> She needs a psychiatrist herself!

> I myself want that car.

> I want that car myself.

Don't confuse this with the use of the pronouns as reflexive pronouns:

> I washed myself.

> I asked myself, "what is the point?"

> I gave myself a pat on the back.